# JQuery datepicker numberOfMonths: display current selection month last

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have a jquery datepicker with the numberOfMonths set to 3, currently when I click on the datepicker, the left side month is the current month. In most cases, the user is only going to be selecting a date prior to todays date so I would prefer the current month selected to be the last calendar i.e. March, April, May instead of the current implementation which is May, June, July.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`showCurrentAtPos` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showCurrentAtPos) just for that purpose:

> Specify where in a multi-month display the current month shows, starting from 0 at the top/left.

The usage looks like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showCurrentAtPos: 2
});​
```

Since it's zero-based, 2 would be the right-most, [you can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BTauz/1/).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Nick, kicking myself for missing that option :)

Comment: Hi nick , I am trying to keep the currently selected month in the same place and not have it rotated. Can you please take a look at this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511051/jquery-ui-multi-date-picker-stop-rotating-months-on-date-select