# jQuery UI Multi Date Picker Stop rotating months on date select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please check the fiddle below. When a date is selected on any calander accept first one, control rotates to make that calendar first one. I want to stop this behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/URcqn/8/

I am using a plugin called Multi Date Picker, but it is basically jQuery Date Picker. When you select a date in 2nd or 3rd month the control rotates months to make the month i selected date on first calendar. How can I stop this behavior ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Jquery Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) which has the feature you are asking for. Personally, i didnt like the UI but you can replace it with Jquery-UI.

Also, the navigation on that page is: You will see some n number of tabs, select "months" tab and see the last example it has multi date picker with behaviour to stop rotation of months.

Code is available... Njoy!!!

Comment: Just shifted to it yesterday!!